# Projecting cash flows via Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: monte-carlo

I am looking to model the cash flows associated with a company as part of a Project finance experiment, where I got the idea from [here](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/financial-theory/08/monte-carlo-multivariate-model.asp). I'm looking to project cash flows for an Automotive company in India upto 2018, given that I have its set of cash flows upto 2014. I was just wondering how I could look to set this up, in terms of the actual model, as I wasn't able to find any relevant documentation.

Also, would the random variables be something like these, where I'll have to assume some sort of distributions based on historical data:
1) Oil prices
2) Price of plastic/steel 
3) Average disposable income of people

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Usually in corporate finance you don't value a firm using monte carlo. 
You define 4-5 scenarios such as: Base Case, Optimistic Case, Conservative Case, Stress Test, and model them accordingly. 
E.g. In your stress test you would have price plastic/steel soaring, average disposable income going down, etc. 
Then you test how much debt the firm can handle and how to optimize its capital structure.

Comment: Thank you. I was just wondering why people don't consider using Monte Carlo Analysis? I realize the relationship between price of plastic and cash flows may not be easily discernible, but can't I run Monte Carlo Simulations to determine the prices of the cars and as a result model cash flows? It seems like it [has been done](https://www.quantnet.com/threads/quant-corporate-finance.9487/#post-89147)

Comment: The reason why they do it is because they have derivatives they want to value/hedge. All the remaining valuation is done using the method I described above. 
Unless you have derivatives to price/hedge there is no need to make Monte Carlo simulations.

Comment: The reason they do it is that most corp finance depts don't have the knowledge/tools to simulate their business plans.  EVERY company could use the more complete picture of risk that a forward sim of their important variables would bring.